# Are any Skeptics users attending the NECSS Conference this year?

Tags: discussion, conference

At least one Stack HQ staffer will be attending the Northeast Conference on Science and Skepticism on April 21-22 in New York City and we would like to know if you will be attending as well! We can provide some swag for you (and more to give out if you'd like), and if there's enough interest we can even host a small, informal meet up in a social manner.

Here is a link to the conference site: http://necss.org/

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bit too far from London...

Comment: I will probably be going.

Comment: I'd like to go, but no one else I know both wants to and can afford to.  Is there a way to directly contact other members if we wanted to arrange that sort of get together?

Comment: I'd say to answer this meta post and then arrange a google hang out, or arrange a time to meet in Chat and discuss it.